# Is there any way to read the header codes without downloading the file at all?

Tags: python, http, header

```
 import httplib
 conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(head)
 conn.request("HEAD",tail)
 res = conn.getresponse()
 print res.status
```

I am currently using this to get the HTTP header code of a file.
However, it seems like this code DOWNLOADS the file, and then gets the code.

However, some files are actually video files...and it would be inefficient for my program to download them.

**Is there any way to read the header codes without downloading the file at all?**

Comment: it depends on how well the server on the other end is well behaved...

Comment: hmm.. if you request a file from a server you make first a connection then you ask for some resource in your case this is the video file. So you download it and finaly your http library gives you the headers back. Thats what i think

Comment: @streetparade: That may be what you think, but it is wrong.  The whole purpose of the `HEAD` command is to tell the server you want only the HTTP headers, not the response body.

Comment: getresponse() does not do what you say it does. Why do you think it's downloading the entire file? You should have an HTTPResponse instance which is ready to read the body of the HTTP response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [HEAD HTTP Method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) like all other HTTP method is just a directive to the server. The HTTP spec says that the server must not return the body in case, but if the server is not implemented or configured correctly then it may return the entire contents of the URL.

There are other factors that may be at play here a proxy server either on your end or on the server end could be caching the content (especially if since it is video) and returning it from a cache. Since the data is coming from a cache full respect of the HTTP specification may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the HTTP `HEAD` command is to return the header information, identical to what you would receive with a `GET` command, but without the response body (e.g. the video itself).  If you are issuing the `HEAD` command and receiving the full body of the response anyway, that sounds like a problem with the server you're connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, if you're getting more than the headers back with the `HEAD` command, the target server is misconfigured.

However, a pragmatic solution to your problem is to simply ask for the first N bytes of the file, and then parse those as a header. Alternatively, stream the connection, periodically parsing for a complete header, and then cancel the download once you've got the header information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use urllib2.open() and get the headers already parsed for you, along with a file-handle ready to read the rest of the data stream. At that point you close the file and don't fetch anything more.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/")
>>> for k,v in f.headers.items():
...     print repr(k), "=", repr(v)
... 
'content-length' = '113782'
'expires' = 'Tue, 17 Nov 2009 22:12:33 GMT'
'server' = 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0'
'connection' = 'close'
'cache-control' = 'private'
'date' = 'Tue, 17 Nov 2009 22:12:33 GMT'
'content-type' = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> f.read(20)
'\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML P'
>>>
```

There should be no reason to generate a HEAD request here.